# Node.js + Apache - https://localhost:3000/socket.io/ ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, sockets, proxypass

I am implementing a simple game in Node.js. I have a `client.js` for my client side code, and a `server.js` running on a remote server, which both use sockets to communicate on **port 3000**

I am also running Apache on **port 80**, and using `ProxyPass` in my apache configuration file, to route the url `mywebsite.io/agario` to my nodejs server.

```
<Location /agario>
     ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
     ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
```

I am also using **cloudflare** to route my webserver 167.179.xx.xx through the url `https://agario.mywebsite.io` for SSL so that I can use HTTPS.

**The problem**

When I try to connect to my website https://agario.mywebsite.io/agario I am receiving the following error:

`socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 GET https://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MakAMgZ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I am unclear why my client code is trying to connect to localhost, when I have specified in the code to connect to the remote server. Potentially I am just confused on how to run the node.js server as this is my first taste of Node.js and sockets.

**client.js**

```
...
var socket;
socket = io.connect('https://agario.mywebsite.io/agario');
...
```

**server.js**

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, listen);

// This call back just tells us that the server has started
function listen() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
}

app.use(express.static('public'));
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection',
  function(socket) {
    console.log("We have a new client: " + socket.id);

...

});
```

*If I have missed out any vital information please let me know and I will update my question, thank you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You server is listening on port 3000 and you're trying to connect with it via 443, you should try something like this

```
socket.connect('https://ip:3000');
```

However, if you're sure that ur client is using the same port as the server or u have a port forwarding then try to use `netcat` just to make sure the the problem is with your script not the network config :

`nc -zv -w1 ip port`

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try this solution out. surely the proxypass in my apache config would do the port handling though?

Comment: running `nc -zv -w1 127.0.0.1 3000` returned `connection to 127.0.0.1 3000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!`

Comment: that means port 3000 is opened and the server is listening which point to my first suggestion .. your client is using port `443` , use the follwoing `.connect('https://ip:3000')`

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have tried changing to `socket.connect('https://<myip>:3000') but I am still seeing the error

Comment: can you share your server's ssl configuration, also run in your terminal this from client side `curl -I https://<myip>` and `curl -I https://<myip>:3000`

Comment: Ok that leads some interesting clues. The first curl returns `SSL: certificate subject name (my company name) does not match target host name 'MYIPADDRESS`

The second curl with port specified returns `gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated`

Comment: That what I thought since ur port is open and the service is up then only thing left is that u miss config ur SSL protocol .. please accept my answer if found helpful

Comment: Thanks for your help, how do I remove this incorrect SSL certificate from my site?

Comment: run the same curl commands but this time use the url instead of the IP address